# Python for loop zip function has more output dictionaries than input keys from old dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, zip

I have a number of dictionaries, all with the same keys. Each dictionary consists of a number of lists with integer values. I want to perform a function on each list in the dictionaries and store the new lists in a new set of dictionaries with the same keys used in the old dictionaries.

I am thinking of using a for loop and a zip function. But in the for loop, the number of keys used to access the lists in the old dictionaries (i.e. key1, key2 ... key4 in the code below) is fewer than the number of lists that will be stored in the new dictionaries, so I don't know how the new lists (i.e. x_scaler, y_scaler) can be assigned to the first two dictionaries (i.e. x_scaler_dic and y_scaler_dic).

```
x_scaler_dic = {}
y_scaler_dic = {}
x_train_scaled_dic = {}
x_test_scaled_dic = {}
y_train_scaled_dic = {}
y_test_scaled_dic = {}

for key1, key2, key3, key4) in zip(x_train_dic, x_test_dic, y_train_dic, y_test_dic):
    x_scaler, y_scaler, x_train_scaled, x_test_scaled, y_train_scaled, y_test_scaled = scale(x_train_dic[key1], x_test_dic[key2], y_train_dic[key3], y_test_dic[key4])
    x_scaler_dic[key?], y_scaler_dic[key?], x_train_scaled_dic[key1], x_test_scaled_dic[key2], y_train_scaled_dic[key3], y_test_scaled_dic[key4] = x_scaler, y_scaler, x_train_scaled, x_test_scaled, y_train_scaled, y_test_scaled
```

scale is a function that scales the lists of the old dictionaries. I added question marks in the code above to indicate that I don't know what the keys for those dictionaries should be.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. What is clear is that if all your dictionaries have the same keys, you do not need to zip the dictionaries. Passing dictionaries to `zip` is the same as passing the keys of the dictionaries. The order of the keys is not even guaranteed to be the same, so zipping will only add confusion. Just iterate over the keys of one dictionary, and act on all dictionaries based on the key.

Comment: What do you mean by allocated list to the dictionaries?

Comment: Hi Amitai Irron. I'd like to perform a function on the lists in the old dictionaries (i.e. x_train_dic, x_test_dic, y_train_dic, y_test_dic) to create a new set of lists. This new set of lists have the same keys from the old dictionaries. I tried using a for loop with a zip function that uses a number of keys (i.e. key1, key2 ... key 4) for each of the old dictionaries. However, the number of keys in the for loop is fewer than the lists created for the new dictionaries. Do you know how I can assign these new lists to the new dictionaries - perhaps even without using the zip function?

Comment: Hello komatiraju032. Sorry for the confusion. By that I mean to say that I want to add the newly created lists (i.e. first line of the for loop: x_scaler, y_scaler, x_train_scaled, x_test_scaled, y_train_scaled, y_test_scaled) to the new dictionaries with the same keys from the old dictionaries. However, the number of keys in the for loop (e.g. key1) are fewer than the number of new lists created in the loop. So would you have any idea how to assign those new lists to the new dictionaries?

Comment: Amitai Irron, your advice worked. I used the keys of one dictionary in the for loop and that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to answer my own question. As suggested by Amitar Irron, you can use the key of one dictionary if the dictionaries have the same keys. The final code:

```
x_scaler_dic = {}
y_scaler_dic = {}
x_train_scaled_dic = {}
x_test_scaled_dic = {}
y_train_scaled_dic = {}
y_test_scaled_dic = {}

for key in x_train_dic:
    x_scaler, y_scaler, x_train_scaled, x_test_scaled, y_train_scaled, y_test_scaled = scale(x_train_dic[key], x_test_dic[key], y_train_dic[key], y_test_dic[key])
    x_scaler_dic[key], y_scaler_dic[key], x_train_scaled_dic[key], x_test_scaled_dic[key], y_train_scaled_dic[key], y_test_scaled_dic[key] = x_scaler, y_scaler, x_train_scaled, x_test_scaled, y_train_scaled, y_test_scaled

print(x_scaler_dic.keys())
print(y_scaler_dic.keys())
print(x_train_scaled_dic.keys())
print(x_test_scaled_dic.keys())
print(y_train_scaled_dic.keys())
print(y_test_scaled_dic.keys())

print result:
dict_keys(['FNS', 'Ohara'])
dict_keys(['FNS', 'Ohara'])
dict_keys(['FNS', 'Ohara'])
dict_keys(['FNS', 'Ohara'])
dict_keys(['FNS', 'Ohara'])
dict_keys(['FNS', 'Ohara'])
```